# Не компилируются стандартные библиотеки в Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Уважаемые коллеги!
Захотелось мне на С++ попрограммировать, а IDE `Visual Studio 2015` ведёт себя очень коварно. Я пытаюсь скомпилировать пустой проект, а она мне:

```
**Error C1083** Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory  ConsoleApplication2 
c:\users\samsung\documents\visual studio 2015\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\stdafx.h
```

Если я напишу в проекте что-то вроде

```
#include <conio.h>
```

Так IDE мне вообще красным подчеркнёт сие. 
Вот скриншоты безобразия:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:**

Что мне нужно поправить в настройках компа или IDE, чтобы всё работало?

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, у установочного файла студии есть опция починки установленной среды

Comment: согласен с @Matty, нужно: Панель управления -> Программы (удаление программы) -> находим Visual Studio -> Изменить -> Repair

Comment: А вы не создавайте пустой проект, это сложнее. Создайте стандартное консольное приложение, должно работать из коробки.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609833/178988

Comment: @VladD, наоборот же, пустой проект проще. Я бы его ещё и совсем подчистил, чтоб безо всяких stdafx.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну вот у ТС возникли проблемы как раз :) Такшта использование пустого проекта предполагает дополнительные телодвижения, в отличие от дефолтного компилируемого проекта, который создаёт визард. Хотя наверное начиная от определённого уровня концептуально легче начинать с пустого проекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё нашлось. Причина всему - `виндовс 10`, которая по умолчанию не хочет работать правильно с `visual studio 15`. После загугливания англоязычных интернетов я решил эту проблему. Более детально:

Внутри `*Visual studio*` изменились пути к **C** заголовкам.

Информацию об этой ошибке можно найти здесь: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/

Мне удалось решить эту непотребность:
Идём в  `Project->Properties->`. В `Configuraton Properties->VC++ Diretories->Library Directories` добавляем пути к `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\`*(Здесь выбираете вашу архитектуру)*

И в `C/C++->General->Additional include directories` в этой строке добавляем путь:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt
```

> Примечание: *10.0.10150.0* может существенно зависеть от вашей версии операционной системы.

**2.** После вышепроделанных манипуляций, у вас может вылезти ошибка `LNK1104 cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib'`. (По крайней мере эта ошибка вылезла у меня).
Как её решить, хорошо показано в [этом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XlypjQUr0J8) видео.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> #include <conio.h>
> ```

Такое больше не существует. В общем-то, не существует нигде кроме Borland C++.

Comment: Извините, не совсем понятно, что значит _не существует_ ?

Comment: а <stdio.h> существует?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, да, `stdio.h` существует. Но stdafx как-то прекомпилируется, так что если оно ломается после подключения conio, то это может быть причиной.

Comment: без коня, с одной стдио не пашет. Такие дела i cry

Comment: Тогда не знаю...

Comment: Ну почему? В Windows Kit есть - ставится вместе с Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

От админа запускаете?
Студия на диск "С" установлена? 
Мб попробовать привилегии повысить для папки, куда установлена VS и "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: от админа, привелегии все есть. Но всё = спасибо.